# Modify map table name in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Here's my class:

```
@Entity (name = "Client")
public abstract class MyClient
{
    private Map<String, String> _properties;
}
```

Hiberate map my properties object into a class named "MyClient_properties".
How can I modify it so it will be mapped to "Client_properties"?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly I thought that is supposed to be the default.  Pretty sure the default naming feature is supposed to take the `@Entity#name` value rather than the class name if it is supplied.

Anyway, to explicitly name the collection table you'd use (oddly enough) the JPA `@CollectionTable` annotation:

```
@CollectionTable( name="Client_properties" )
private Map<String, String> _properties;
```